# Как передать query string при подключении к вебсокету OKX?

Tags: python, websocket

пишу приложение на Python и возникла необходимость воспользоваться вебсокетом от OKX, нужно получать книгу ордеров. В [документации](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/?shell#order-book-trading-market-data-ws-order-book-channel) нашёл какие параметры нужно передавать и попытался написать код. К вебсокету подключаюсь, но никаких данных от туда не получают, подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема? Думаю что проблема кроется в том что я неправильно передаю параметры

```
import websockets
import asyncio


async def on_message(message):
    print("publicCallback", message)


async def main():
    url = 'wss://ws.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/public?op=subscribe&args=[{"channel":"books","instId":"BTC-USDT"}]'
    async with websockets.connect(url) as client:
        while True:
            print(await client.recv())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Так вы в него ничего не отправляется кроме параметров. После handshake с сокетом нужно общаться.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Сейчас оформлю в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/?shell#overview-websocket-subscribe) в документации, описано, как подписаться на получение сообщений.
Прежде чем перекладывать на код, потренироваться можно в [POSTMAN](https://www.postman.com/):

[image: Скриншот POSTMAN показывающий работу сокета]

Работает.

Забираем это же сообщение в Python:

```python
from websocket import create_connection
import json

request = {
  "op": "subscribe",
  "args": [
    {
      "channel": "books",
      "instId": "BTC-USDT"
    }
  ]
}

ws = create_connection('wss://ws.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/public')

ws.send(json.dumps(request))
response = ws.recv()
print(response)
```

###### Вывод:

```
'{"event":"subscribe","arg":{"channel":"books","instId":"BTC-USDT"}}'
```

Для простоты примера я не использовал асинхрон, но ничто не мешает вам получать сообщения после отправки подписки точно так же, как вы это хотели делать в вопросе.

Поясню ещё чуть подробнее про сообщение. То что вы делаете, вы соединяетесь с сокетом, и передаёте параметры при попытке соединения, но для соединения они не нужны, поэтому дальше ничего и не происходит. После подключения необходимо сокету отправить сообщение, вот в нём то, как раз, и необходимо ваши параметры перечислить.